# Big $O$ notation and Chebyshev's theorem

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

By Chebyshev we have that, $$n\geq\frac{ap_{n}}{\log(p_{n})}$$

Where $p_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ smallest prime and $a$ is constant. I have seen that from this, the implication that $\log(p_{n})=O(\log(n))$ and substituting back in that $p_{n}=O(n\log(n))$ however I am unsure of the steps that allow us to arrive at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logarithm is monotonically increasing, therefore inequalities between positive expressions are preserved when taking logarithms. Thus from Chebyshev's bound we obtain
$$\log n \geqslant \log p_n - \log \log p_n + \log a\,. \tag{$\ast$}$$
Differentiation shows that $\frac{\log x}{x}$ attains its maximum $\frac{1}{e}$ at $x = e$, hence
$$\log n \geqslant \biggl(1 - \frac{\log \log p_n}{\log p_n}\biggr)\log p_n + \log a \geqslant \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{e}\biggr)\log p_n + \log a$$
and by rearranging
$$\log p_n \leqslant \frac{e}{e-1}\biggl(\log n + \log \frac{1}{a}\biggr)$$
which yields
$$\log p_n \leqslant \frac{2e}{e-1}\log n$$
for $n \geqslant e^{1/a}$. Thus $\log p_n \in O(\log n)$. In fact, we can easily obtain the sharper $\log p_n \sim \log n$. On the one hand, $p_n \geqslant n$ and consequently $\log p_n \geqslant \log n$ is clear, and if we divide $(\ast)$ by $\log n$ (for $n \geqslant 2$) we obtain
$$1 \geqslant \biggl(1 - \frac{\log \log p_n}{\log p_n}\biggr)\frac{\log p_n}{\log n} + \frac{\log a}{\log n}\,.$$
Since $\frac{\log a}{\log n} \to 0$ and $\frac{\log \log p_n}{\log p_n} \to 0$ it follows that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log p_n}{\log n} \leqslant 1\,.$$
Since all terms of that sequence are $\geqslant 1$ this means
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log p_n}{\log n} = 1\,,$$
i.e. $\log p_n \sim \log n$.

Then Chebyshev's inequality yields
$$p_n \leqslant \frac{1}{a}n\log p_n \leqslant \frac{C}{a}n\log n$$
for $n \geqslant 2$ where
$$C = \max\: \biggl\{\frac{\log p_n}{\log n} : n \geqslant 2\biggr\}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\log(p_n) = O(\log(n))$, there exists a constant $C$ such that $\log(p_n) \leq C\cdot\log(n)$ for all $n$. So
$$ n\geq \frac{ap_n}{\log(p_n)} \geq \frac{ap_n}{C\log(n)} $$
and
$$p_n\leq \frac{C\cdot n \log(n)}{a}.$$
Thus there exists a constant $K = C/a$ such that for all $n$, $p_n \leq K\cdot n\log(n)$. So $p_n = O(n\log(n))$.

Comment: If we had no prior knowledge that $log(p_{n})=O(log(n))$ how could we arrive at this from $n\geq \frac{ap_{n}}{log(p_{n})}$

Comment: Hmmm it seems I misunderstood your question then. I don't think it's possible to derive just from the inequality. What exactly is $p_n$?

Comment: $p_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ smallest prime

Comment: Okay I'll play around with it some more; in the meantime, could you update your question to include more information on where these values come from? I'm not exactly sure it's possible to derive just from the information given (but I could be wrong!)

Comment: Yes absolutely!